# Panache under Quarkus giving timeout for db update

Tags: java, timeout, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have the following api in my Quarkus application:

```
  @PATCH
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Transactional
  public Uni<Response> updateCustomer(@RestPath Long id, MyPatchObject myBody) {
    return myService.updateCustomer(id, myBody);
  }
```

Inside my service:

```
  public Uni<Response> updateCustomer(final long id, final MyPatchObject myBody) {
    return myRepo.findById(id) 
// some validation here
        .replaceWith(myRepo.update(id, myBody)
                           .chain(() -> myRepo.flush())
// reload to get the latest changes
                           .replaceWith(myRepo.findById(id)) 
// some other handling that persits to another repository
        .replaceWith(Response.noContent().build());
  }
```

And my Repository:

```
  public Uni<Integer> update(Long id, MyPatchObject params) {
    // Some handling which results in these constants:
    String query = "black_listed = :blacklisted where id = :id"
    Parameters params = ... // contains: [blacklisted-true, id-1]
    return this.update(query,params);
  }
```

I am however getting this timeout exception when I try to call this api through my test

```
2021-10-07 12:40:28,911 ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) Request failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.executeInVertxEventLoop(AbstractJpaOperations.java:52)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniRunSubscribeOn.subscribe(UniRunSubscribeOn.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.DefaultUniEmitter.complete(DefaultUniEmitter.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnNull.lambda$failWith$1(UniOnNull.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualBiConsumer.accept(SlowContextualBiConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.lambda$transformToUni$4(UniOnItem.java:169)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter.subscribe(UniCreateWithEmitter.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onItem(UniOperatorProcessor.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2143)
    at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$toCompletionStage$2(Future.java:360)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:102)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:35)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.complete(Promise.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:29)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:81)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:173)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onSuccess(PromiseImpl.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:41)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.command.CommandResponse.fire(CommandResponse.java:46)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.handleMessage(SocketConnectionBase.java:287)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.PgSocketConnection.handleMessage(PgSocketConnection.java:96)
    at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.lambda$init$0(SocketConnectionBase.java:99)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.lambda$new$1(NetSocketImpl.java:97)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:240)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.lambda$handleMessage$9(NetSocketImpl.java:390)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:50)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:274)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:22)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:155)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:154)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.lambda$write$0(PgEncoder.java:87)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgCommandCodec.handleReadyForQuery(PgCommandCodec.java:139)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.decodeReadyForQuery(PgDecoder.java:237)
    at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.channelRead(PgDecoder.java:96)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1956)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2091)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.executeInVertxEventLoop(AbstractJpaOperations.java:50)
    ... 86 more
```

I did find some code in io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations

```
    // FIXME: make it configurable?
    static final long TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
```

which seems related but not sure if the root cause of the issue.

My update query is running to update a single field, filtered by ID of the entries, in a table that has only the one record in it so it's not a matter of database optimisation for sure. What could possibly be causing the error?

Comment: Are you aware that the update is being execute before the completion of the first findById?

Comment: The update returns a uni so it should not be executed before then?

Comment: The methods that returns Uni executes some (but not necessarily all) work in other threads. Unis are lazy and will only do their jobs after being subscribed and **maybe** things are being executed at the correct order in your code but you cannot trust libs implementations that might have some sync code before the async code. You should use replaceWith for sync code and methods like call and chain for async code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i encountered this again and had to solve this again.

The issue i had was that I was calling `panacheRepository.persistAndFlush` to generate a uni, and then passing it through `.chain(myUni)`

this triggered the timeout in `AbstractJpOperations`

instead i needed to make sure that the `persistAndFlush` uni is called within a lambda inside the `.chain` and cannot be prepared beforehand.

This feels like unintentional behaviour really since the creation of a uni shouldn't execute anything which is triggering a timeout imo

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure this is what is causing your problem, but you should use `Uni#replaceWith` and `Uni#invoke` for sync and `Uni#call` and `Uni#chain` for async code, like this:

```
public Uni<Customer> updateCustomer(final long id, final MyPatchObject myBody) {
    return myRepo.findById(id)
        .invoke(customer -> myValidationMethod(customer))
        .call(() -> myRepo.update(id, myBody)) // .call propagates the incoming Uni
        .call(() -> myRepo.flush())
        .chain(() -> myRepo.findById(id)); // .chain propagates the returned Uni
}
```

And just to be picky, do not return Response from your services :)

```
@PATCH
@Path("/{id}")
@Transactional
public Uni<Response> updateCustomer(@RestPath Long id, MyPatchObject myBody) {
    return myService.updateCustomer(id, myBody)
        .replaceWith(Response.noContent().build());
}
```

Mutiny has a very confusing nomenclature after all...